# Linq Expression For DateTime Equality Nullable Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to search DateTime data field from an SQL Server using the following code snippet:

```
DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse("14-11-2016");
```

As you can see the toDate field is not null.

```
var maxComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(
                Expression.Invoke(searchColumnName, row),
                typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(DateTime) }),
                Expression.Constant(toDate, typeof(DateTime))),
                Expression.Constant(0, typeof(DateTime)));
```

When this code rude, the following error is displayed when maxComparisonExpression is executed.

```
Method 'Int32 CompareTo(System.DateTime)' declared on type 'System.DateTime' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'
```

So far I have changed the typeof(DateTime) to typeof(DateTime?), this had no effect.

I think it has something to do with the second parameter

```
Expression.Constant(0, typeof(DateTime))
```

But I cannot see how to fix this. Can anyone show me some pointers in fixing this?

UPDATE:

I have a page that is used for an advanced search. On this page are over twenty search fields, each having a select dropdown providing comparison operators like: equals, less than, greater then, etc.

So I am writing some expressions to deal with specific data types. This in time will be converted using a generic pattern into a library.

Using the following code to define [field] == fromInt executes fine in Linqpad

```
int fromInt = 101462975;

Expression<Func<Table_Name, int>> searchColumnName = x => x.Id;

IQueryable<Table_Name> retval = Entities.Table_Name.AsQueryable();

var row = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Table_Name), "Table_Name");

var ComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(
                           Expression.Invoke(searchColumnName, row),
                           typeof(int).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(int) }),
                           Expression.Constant(fromInt)),
                           Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int)));
```

So and assumption of changing the datatype of int to DateTime was assumed to be the way forward.

The full code from LinqPad is:

```
DateTime? toDate = DateTime.Parse("14-11-2016");

Expression<Func<Table_Name, DateTime?>> searchColumnName = x => x.Created_date;

IQueryable<Table_Name> retval = Entities.Table_Name.AsQueryable();

var row = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Table_Name), "Table_Name");

var ComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(
                           Expression.Invoke(searchColumnName, row),
                           typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(DateTime) }),
                           Expression.Constant(toDate, typeof(DateTime))),
                           Expression.Constant(0, typeof(DateTime)));
```

I have tried changing the line above to

```
Expression.Constant(0));
```

But this just throws the same error, I then replaced the constant will a null value to give me:

```
var ComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(
                           Expression.Invoke(searchColumnName, row),
                           typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(DateTime) }),
                           Expression.Constant(toDate, typeof(DateTime))),
                           null);
```

Although this did not work, the error provided was indicating that it did not like the null value parameter.

I have come across the following link [How to compare only date part with linq expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296071/how-to-compare-only-date-part-with-linq-expression)

I have tried what is suggested in here whereby it suggests that a between operation is required. Is also did not work.

Comment: There are many errors in this snippet, fixing one would just get you to the next. The original exception indicates  that the type of `Expression.Invoke(searchColumnName, row)` is `DateTime?`. You'd better tell us what are you trying to achieve and show the whole method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outcome of `CompareTo` is an integer, although you want to compare the outcome with a `DateTime`:

```
Expression.Constant(0, typeof(DateTime /* oops */))
```

That makes no sense, does it? Compare with an `int`:

```
Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int))
```

In this case you could simply omit the type:

```
Expression.Constant(0)
```

---

Another problem is that `Expression.Invoke(searchColumnName, row)` returns a `DateTime?`, not a `DateTime`. You have to convert that one way or another. You could add a `GetDateTimeValue` method:

```
var ComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(
                           GetDateTimeValue(Expression.Invoke(searchColumnName, row)),
                           typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(DateTime) }),
                           Expression.Constant(toDate, typeof(DateTime))),
                           null);
```

Where `GetDateTimeValue` is:

```
private readonly static MethodInfo nullableDateTimeGetValueOrDefaultMethodInfo = typeof(DateTime?).GetMethod(nameof(Nullable<DateTime>.GetValueOrDefault), new Type[] { });

private static Expression GetDateTimeValue(Expression expr)
{
    return Expression.Call(expr, nullableDateTimeGetValueOrDefaultMethodInfo);
}
```